# if loop syntax error

Tags: python

Is the following syntax right in Python?

```
(if 'SU' in line or 'AU' in line or 'VU' in line or 'rf' in line and line.find('/*') == -1) and (BUILDROOT in line):
    lineMatch = False
```

Comment: The `if`-statement does not start a loop.

Comment: What is the result of running your code? The exception you get should tell you its not correct.

Comment: You should remove the `(` from before the `if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if any(x in line for x in ('SU', 'AU', 'VU', 'rf')) and '/*' not in line and BUILDROOT in line:
    lineMatch = False
```

Answer (score 5):

No, the `if` should not be inside the brackets.